# Modal closing in Expo, cannot find variable SetModelVisible

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react-native, doing this with Expo. Can someone explain me how I can close my Modal?

```
const Foobar = (props) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Modal
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={_closeModal.bind(this)}
      >
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>
                Foobar
            </Text>
            <Button onPress={() => { theAction(); }} 
            title="I want to click this button and close the Modal when I confirm this action with 'YES'" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

let _closeModal = () => {
  setModalVisible(false);
};

let theAction = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Confirm",
    "Yes or No?",
    [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => {
          _closeModal();
        },
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
      },
    ]
  );
};
```

I get this error now: "**can't find variable: setModalVisible**"

Hopefully someone is willing to explain what I did wrong, so I can learn from this. Google isn't that of a help with this specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use component state outside of your component. You can however pass your state object to children using props. However for this solution try like this -

```
const Foobar = (props) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(true);

const _closeModal = () => {
  setModalVisible(false);
};

const theAction = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Confirm",
    "Yes or No?",
    [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        onPress: () => {
          _closeModal();
        },
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
      },
    ]
  );
};
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Modal
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={_closeModal.bind(this)}
      >
        <View>
          <View>
            <Text>
                Foobar
            </Text>
            <Button onPress={() => { theAction(); }} 
            title="I want to click this button and close the Modal when I confirm this action with 'YES'" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can also use react redux to manage state variables used by many components which may not be the child component. Another alternative is Context API.